# Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY000) SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'verifyToten' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, email-verification, laravel-5.7

I want to create and store a verify token in the database to activate the user's account after registration. But I'm getting the above error.
Can you help please.

**Users Table**

```
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone',10)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('verifyToten');
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**User model**

```
   protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'phone', 'password','verifyToten'
];
```

**Register Controller**

```
        return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'verify_token' => Str::random(40),
    ]);
```

Comment: you are trying to fill `verify_token` but your database field is `verifyToken`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your user migration your field name is  `$table->string('verifyToten');` while in your register controller you are saving value for `'verify_token' => Str::random(40)` change `verify_token` to `verifyToten` in your controller